# Is there a Java Spring + REST Services + MongoDB + Swagger Project for reference?

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, glassfish, swagger

I am trying to build a project with the following:

- Maven, So I can build quickly & deploy on Glassfish, I don't really want a Spring Boot.
- Should have REST - I would like to use Controller, Service, Repository Annotations.
- MongoDB as the backend, I want to see MongoRepository in action, but I have been constantly running into multiple issues & I am really tired of solving them & they keep coming back always.
- Swagger API Integration

I really appreciate if someone can point me to any application on Github or somewhere for my reference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the guides at https://spring.io/guides and also at the official `Spring` blog: https://spring.io/blog

Answer (score -1):

I have done a basic one, [Click here](https://github.com/anilpasham5/UserSA-API.git) to get that